# Компонент TChart со своими данными на оси

Tags: delphi

Есть лист с данными:

`...
48,47 11:07:53:810
...`

Вопрос: как поместить `11:07:53:810` на ось графика как значение, а то у меня выдаётся ошибка о не совместимости формата?

Comment: Вы выложите кусок своего кода укажите строку где ошибка, и какая ошибка и вам помогут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поступил так: 
обрезал все, что после секунд и

```
var t:TTime;
begin
 t:=StrToTime(11:07:53);
end;
```

Все работает. Может быть, кому-то поможет.